# Convolution of two functions is a constant

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

I have the convolution of two functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ is a constant $K \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e., $(f*g)(t) = K$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Taking Fourier transform of the convolution yields 
$$
F(s)G(s) = K \delta(s)
$$ 
with $F(s)$ and $G(s)$ being the Fourier transform of $f$ and $g$ respectively and $\delta(\cdot)$ being the Dirac Delta function. 
Can I conclude that $f$ or $g$ must be a constant ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't.  For example, consider the situation

$$
F(s) = \delta(s) + \delta(s-1) + \delta(s+1)\\
G(s) = e^{-s^2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} s\right)
$$

---

Counterexample that I'm not sure of:

$$
F(s) = \delta(s) + \delta(s-1) + \delta(s+1)\\
G(s) = \delta(s) + \delta(s-2) + \delta(s+2)
$$

Comment: How does one define the product of two Dirac distributions?

Comment: @DanielFischer [it seems this isn't such an easy issue to deal with after all](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48067/is-square-of-delta-function-defined-somewhere).

Comment: I cleaned up the comment thread, hope you don't mind. (I can undelete the comments if you do.) I left the link to the MO thread and its motivation, because I think that's interesting.